# Grails check for unique constraint

Tags: grails, groovy

I have a Domain class Supplier:-

```
class Supplier {

    static embedded=['address']
    static constraints = {
        vendorName(blank:false,nullable:false,maxSize:50)
        address(blank:false,nullable:false,unique:true)
        contactPerson(blank:false,nullable:false,maxSize:50)

    }
    String vendorName
    Address address
    String contactPerson
}
```

and the Address class:-

```
class Address {
    String street
    String area

    static constraints = {
        street(blank:false,nullable:false)
        area(blank:false,nullable:false)
    }

}
```

My requirement is to check for the uniqueness of street in supplier. when a user enter street and area from Supplier view, i have to check that street should be unique for a vendor.

thnks

Comment: Are you checking the uniqueness of a street in a supplier, or a street towards a vendor?  Can you provide the vendor class?

Comment: vendor name is string in supplier but Address is a class. I have to check that for a vendor their can be one or more street but for a street their is only one vendor.

Comment: Follows from it that your street has to be a PK in Address. Just make address unique in Supplier.

Comment: By making address unique in supplier, it checks for both the street and area. if i insert same value for street and different value for area, the row get inserted. and also it is not checking for case sensitivity.

Answer (score 1):

It will be like that if only street should be unique

```
class Address {
    String street
    String area

    static constraints = {
        street(blank:false,nullable:false)
        area(blank:false,nullable:false)
    }
    static mapping = {
        street(index: true, indexAttributes: [unique: true])
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you only have one Address per Supplier street is already unique per Supplier.  If you can't have more than 1 address you can't have duplicate streets.